# How to save Kerberos private credentials for use in other machines

Tags: java, kerberos, jaas

I am using JAAS to get Kerberos credentials. My config file look like this:

```
SignedOnUserLoginContext
{
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required debug=true useTicketCache=true doNotPrompt=true;
};
```

The code to get Kerberos credentials

```
try {           
        LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("SignedOnUserLoginContext");
        lc.login();
        Subject signedOnUserSubject = lc.getSubject();
        Set<Object> privateCred = signedOnUserSubject.getPrivateCredentials();

            for (Object privates : privateCred) {
                if (privates instanceof KerberosTicket) {
                    KerberosTicket ticket = (KerberosTicket)privates;
                    return ticket.getEncoded();
                }
            }

    }
```

When i transfer the ticket to other machines and using JAAS to login using Kerberos, it doesn't get authenticated. my config file at receiving:

```
 KrbLogin{
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
            principal=principal@realm
            useTicketCache="FILE:///where i store the ticket"
 };
```

I am suspecting I cannot just get the ticket like that, but need to get the whole private credentials returned by getPrivateCredentials(). Also, using doNotPrompt=true and useTicketCache=true I am trying to get from Windows cache.

I read in [some Java security book](http://goo.gl/ON4iXT) that private credentials can include other data such as private keys, encryption keys, password etc...

Hence, i would need to get the return value of getPrivateCredentials(). How can get what is returned by getPrivateCredentials() into an actual Kerberos credential file. I read in order to access these data, I would need to use [PrivateCredentialPermission](http://goo.gl/Lspz5w) module. Is there example to show how to do this?

Comment: You problem is a pain in the ass and not intended to be done with Kerberos. Perform a kinit on the machine you intend to use that TGT. More over, JGSS does *not* provide a high-level API for exporting credentials. MIT Kerberos does.

Answer (score 1):

Credentials of Kerberos is not portable, technically, you cannot do **kinit** on machine *A* and then use that TGT (ticket granting ticket) or ST (service ticket) on machine *B* (except for delegation), because both TGT and ST contains encrypted IP address of client.

ST is encrypted by service server's key, which means only SS can verify/read content of the ticket.

TGT is encrypted by key of a TGS (ticket granting server).

By the way, maybe what you want is what called **Kerberos keytab** --- which contains principal's `user name` & `password`.

But, transferring keytab through network is dangerous and deprecated.

Comment: Actually you can. I did kinit on one machine and bring to anther. then use Krb5loginmodule with ticket="where i store my kinit cache". This is how a credential cache file works right? you can use it to login to kerberos w/o using password.

Comment: Ip address is optional on the original request that created the tgt